# Repeater with Radiobutton get selected row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a repeater control in asp.net

when a readio button is clicked i want to alert the corresponding textbox value

```
<itemtemplate> 
    <div class="Class1 subclass1 subclass2 "> 
        <asp:RadioButton CssClass="Class2" ID="rbOne" runat="server" 
            GroupName="GroupItems"  /> 
        //Some other controls 

        <asp:Panel class="myPanel mYText" style="display:none;" runat="server" id="MyPnl"> 
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbValue" CssClass="SomeClass" MaxLength="11" 
                    Text=""></asp:TextBox> 
        </asp:Panel> 
    </div> 
</itemtemplate>
```

using jQuery how can i get the selected textbox value like in alert

Comment: How do you tell which TextBox map to the RadioButton?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could give you the selected input

```
$('div.Class1 input[type=radio]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.myPanel').find('input.SomeClass').val()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('<%=tbValue.ClientID%>').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add javascript event onchange and use the give jquery selectors.

**Html**

```
<asp:RadioButton CssClass="Class2" ID="rbOne" runat="server" onchange="RadioClicked(this);"
                                        GroupName="GroupItems" onclick="GetValue()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function RadioClicked(rad)
{
     alert("change fired");
     alert($(rad).closest('.Class1.subclass1.subclass2').find('.SomeClass').val());
}
```

**Update on OP request** *for getting value of textbox out side repeater*

```
function RadioClicked(rad)
{
      alert($('<%= tbValue.ClientID %>').val());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i have to get the selected value of the Texbox on button click which is outside the repeater

Comment: Updated my answer, is this what you require?

Comment: still i am not getting it, i have updated my code, see the question. should i follow some class hierarchy, can you please specify the exact syntax of class that i have to use

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if you get first alert message, i.e.  alert("change fired");

Comment: I am getting the alert, i have slightly modified, i have added a custom validator for Textbox, onclientside vaidation i am writing like this                                                            var selText = jQuery("Class1 input[type=radio][id$=rbVehicle]:checked").closest(".mYText").find("input[type=text][id$=tbValue]").val();  still get undefined

Comment: I updated my answer, please test, also remove space after subclass2 <div class="Class1 subclass1 subclass2 "> should be <div class="Class1 subclass1 subclass2">

Comment: I dont want the onchange event of radiobutton, i want on button click which is outside the repeater, the textbox has client validation function, on the button click which is outside repeater i want to get the selected radiobutton clicked value

Comment: ok, it works now, thanks. but since i have custom validator in item template it fires twice. how can i avoid this

Comment: I am not very clear about what exactly going on your side but you can have a global variable and use it as a flag. So that when first event fires you set its value let assume flagIsFirstEventFired = true; and in second do process only if flagIsFirstEventFired = false; also set it to false in second event